# LinkerD Cert Rotation not clearly described in the Documents

Tags: linkerd, servicemesh

I have started working with LinkerD recently and trying to set it up on the cluster.
The issue I am facing is with the cert rotation. The LinkerD documentation does not elaborate completely on the process of how the issuer cert is used to generate the CSR for the Proxy request and also it does not mention how Cert Manager could be used to store the issuer cert.

If I am not missing something could you please point me to the documentation that completely elaborates the same?

Also, I want to clarify if we just generate the root cert and intermediate cert, later inject it using `--identity-trust-anchors-file` and
`--identity-issuer-certificate-file` will that work or we need to find specifically how to rotate the certs.

I may be posting on the wrong channel but the lack of documentation caused me to ask the above questions.